# I want to extract all occurring text between "CREATE INDEX" and ")" on the following text

Tags: notepad++

I have a text looking like this. But there are thousands of lines to the text. I want to extract text from this and only get the index data.

```
CREATE INDEX "SCHEMA"."INDEX_NAME1" ON "SCHEMA"."TABNAME1" 
        ("COLX" ASC)
        
        COMPRESS NO 
        INCLUDE NULL KEYS ALLOW REVERSE SCANS;

-- DDL Statements for Indexes on Table "CBLOSUAT"."KCR_PRODUCT"

SET SYSIBM.NLS_STRING_UNITS = 'SYSTEM';

CREATE INDEX "SCHEMA"."INDEX_NAME2" ON "SCHEMA"."TABNAME2"  
        ("COL1" ASC,
         "COL2" ASC)
        
        COMPRESS NO 
        INCLUDE NULL KEYS ALLOW REVERSE SCANS;
```

I want something like

```
CREATE INDEX "SCHEMA"."INDEX_NAME1" ON "SCHEMA"."TABNAME1" 
        ("COLX" ASC)

CREATE INDEX "SCHEMA"."INDEX_NAME2" ON "SCHEMA"."TABNAME2"  
        ("COL1" ASC,
         "COL2" ASC)
```

I am getting the text by using "CREATE INDEX[^;]+;" in search mode but now I want to select all of the code and copy it to another text file or create a new text file or delete the rest of the code while keeping what I want.

Comment: Please [edit] the question then, and use the preview to make sure that the text you are going to submit is rendered as you expect.

Comment: Oh Thanks, I couldn't find the edit option

Comment: Anyways I found the answer to be the regex "CREATE INDEX[^;]+;" in search mode.

Comment: Your regex matches everything from `CREATE INDEX` to the first semicolon, so it will also include the lines beginning with `COMPRESS` and `INCLUDE`, based on the example I don't think you want them, do you? Anyway, from the Find menu you can click on the 5th tab, "Mark". From there you can "Mark All", then "Copy Marked Text", and then paste it into another file.

Comment: yeah, of course, it should be matching ")" but for my use case by solution was fine as I can remove the bottom part because it's just repeating itself. But not the perfect solution I agreed.

Comment: Oh this worked "CREATE INDEX[^;]+\Q)\E"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h*CREATE INDEX.+?\(.+?\)\R(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **TICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
\h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
CREATE INDEX    # literally
.+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
\(              # opening parenthesis
.+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
\)              # closing parenthesis
\R              # any kind of linebreak
(*SKIP)         # forget this match
(*FAIL)         # and considere the match has failed
  |               # OR
.               # any character
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! this solved my issue the fastest way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by the way. I first used "CREATE INDEX[^;]+\Q)\E" in the regex search mode. Then marked it and copy it from the options provided by the notepad++

[Steps to mark and copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt4PM.png)

Comment: Please include all necessary information in the answer, in descriptive text format for example. Consider what happens if the external image host disappears permanently.